# How to add counter in laravel chunk without closure?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 100000 data which I want to enter at a time, for that I use chunk, but, chunk cannot display the results of the counter that I have made.

This is my code:

```
$sbuLocationArray = [];
$mergeArray = [];
$insert_data = collect($map);
$chunks = $insert_data->chunk(500);
$loop = 0;
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    SBU::insert($chunk->toArray());
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($provincesName[$loop]); $i++) {
        $locationId = Location::where('name', $provincesName[$loop][$i])->select('id')->first();
        $id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();;
        $sbuLocationArray[] = ['sbu_id' => $id, 'location_id' => $locationId->id, 'created_by' => $user, 'updated_by' => $user, 'created_at' => Carbon::now(), 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()];
    }
    $loop++;
}
SBULocation::insert($sbuLocationArray);

return $loop;
```

In my code I have `$loop` the value of `$loop` is a counter value from count array on foreach, I will use it to set an index of `$provincesName`

Comment: where is this code called? Where does $loop get returned to?

Comment: i just return the $loop to show the counter, but $loop show is 1, if my data is 5, $loop still 1

Comment: what does the calling code look like?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I didn't get it

Comment: just a suggestion use Query Builder for retrieving location id. QB is faster than eloquent

Comment: ok I get it, thanks, it reduce time load data, although it is almost close to my expectations, but thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    foreach ($chunk as $data) {
        $loop++; // $loop here
    }

    // Not here
}
```

Comment: how about the data execution time ?, in here i use queue to insert 100.000 data into data base , and the data execution time is 49 seconds, before it I just input data on one table, but in this case I using variable $locationId to inserting to SBULocation

Comment: in this code, the SBU::insert($chunk->toArray()); is in this first foreach or this foreach just for $loop ?

Comment: it's work!! thanks, so I can use this loop for index

Comment: Glad to hear that :)